# 'or' and '||' - asking for x or y in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in `application.html.erb`

```
...
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <section class="<%= "login_section" if login_or_signup? %>"> #here's the issue
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

`login_section` is a css class that formats the header differently, and I'd like that to be set only if the current path is `/login` or `/signup` - so the `login_or_signup?` helper is defined like so:

```
def login_or_signup?
  request.path == login_path || signup_path
end
```

I've also tried the guts of that as `login_path or signup_path`, `(login_path || signup_path)`, and `(login_path or signup_path)` but none of them will evaluate to `true` correctly ("correctly" being when the path is *either* `/login` or `/signup`).  I've tried writing this as

```
def login_or_signup?
  request.path == login_path
end
```

and that works as expected.

Comment: You should think it the other way: `[login_path, signup_path].include?(request.path)` - But I'm not sure how it will react with GET params and extra stuff in the URL

Comment: Your statement `request.path == login_path || signup_path` is wrong. This way you are comparing `request.path` with the result of `login_path || signup_path` which is always true. It is the same like `request.path == true` which will always return true too.

Comment: That's not correct. I thought so too, at first, but actually `request.path == login_path || signup_path` should return `true` if `request.path == login_path` and it should return `/signup` otherwise. The equality is evaluated before the disjunction. At least in ruby 2.0. Also, `login_path || signup_path` would evaluate to a string anyway, not a boolean.

Comment: Actually you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about

```
def login_or_signup?
  current_page?(:login) || current_page?(:signup)
end
```

**[API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F)**